# Are focus-related eye diseases like myopia and astigmatism reversible?

Tags: eye

Are those diseases recoverable without surgeries, glasses or contact lens? Maybe by eye exercises?

Edit: Once I saw on YouTube a man that managed to recover his eyes from these conditions by eye exercises. He even got his driver's license without using eye glasses. Is it really possible?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: This has been answered [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/strange-way-of-improving-eyesight-could-it-work) and [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/138/is-the-bates-method-for-improving-eyesight-efficacious).